# onload from external js file

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm writing a js script that people will add to their web site by adding a single line of code to the header or end of the body part of their HTML.

My question is how to do the onload right on the external js file. Will the code below work? Can't it possibly run after the onload of the document and miss the onload event?

```
function c_onload () {  alert ('onload'); }

if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent('onload', c_onload);}
else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load', c_onload, false);}
else {document.addEventListener('load', c_onload, false);}
```

(I can't use Jquery or any other library)

Comment: I know this is a really old thread, but I had a similar problem and a user on here helped me solve this problem without the need for any third party libraries, i.e. JQuery.

Here's my post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401571/external-js-with-onload-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that if you can't use jQuery or some other library you need to reproduce a way good deal of their functionality. The reason is that browsers handle the onLoad event differently.

I recommend that you download jQuery's code and see how the documentready function is implemented.

Comment: +1 because reproducing what jquery does is essentially what the OP will have to do

Comment: -1: browsers don't handle `onload` differntly - the problem lies with `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: To be honest I didn't know that. I've always have taken as best practice to use jQuery's document ready function. If you are allowed to use jQuery, this always works and saves you from diving into the internals of the browsers.

Comment: @kgiannakakis: It's just that `window.onload` and `DOMContentLoaded` do different things - the first one waits for external ressources, the second one doesn't. Depending on what you're trying to do, `window.onload` might actually be the better solution...

Comment: btw, for Nir's question, it shouldn't matter if you use `window.onload` or `DOMContentLoaded` - scripts are part of the DOM, so both shouldn't fire before all referenced scripts have been included...

Answer (score 4):

What is your last `else`-clause

```
else {document.addEventListener('load', c_onload, false);
```

for? It's rather useless, imho.

The following should be a cross-browser solution: It first checks for `addEventListener()`, then `attachEvent()` and falls back to `onload = ...`

```
function chain(f1, f2) {
    return typeof f1 !== 'function' ? f2 : function() {
        var r1 = f1.apply(this, arguments),
            r2 = f2.apply(this, arguments);
        return typeof r1 === 'undefined' ? r2 : (r1 && r2);
    };
}

function addOnloadListener(func) {
    if(window.addEventListener) 
        window.addEventListener('load', func, false);
    else if(window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent('onload', func);
    else window.onload = chain(window.onload, func);
}
```

Also, what kgiannakakis stated

> The reason is that browsers handle the onLoad event differently.

is not true: all major browsers handle `window.onload` the same way, ie the listener function gets executed after the external resources - **including your external script** - have been loaded. The problem lies with `DOMContentLoaded` - that's where the hacks with `doScroll()`, `defer`, `onreadystatechange` and whatever else someone has cooked up come to play.

---

Depending on your target audience, you may either want to drop the fallback code or even use it exclusively. My vote would go for dropping it.

Answer (score 0):

The [onLoad](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onload.asp) event is supposed to be run when the element it is attached to is loaded. But some browsers* misinpret this as "beforeload" or "sometime during load" so the safest option to be sure something is run after all html is loaded, is to add a call to the function on the bottom of the HTML source, like this:

```
    ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            c_onload();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(* at least some versions of Safari for Windows I do beleave have this issue)