# External JS with onLoad Event

Tags: onload, external-js

I have an external js file which has a function that is meant to run AFTER the document body has loaded. This is what I have so far but it's not working as it should. Some help please.

**External JS File**

```
window.document.body.addEventListener('load', numOfSelects());

function numOfSelects()
{
  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  alert(selects.length);
}
```

The HTML file that calls this script does have a few select fields. The alert works but it shows 0. And after the alert shows then the body can be seen loaded. Obviously this is not what I wanted. What am I doing wrong? Thanks guys.

I have also tried this:

Still didn't work. Here's my code:

**Parent File**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File 1</title>
<script src='file1.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

<select id='dd1'><option>First</option><option>Second</option></select>
<select id='dd2'><option>First</option><option>Second</option></select>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS FILE**

```
alert('start');
window.document.body.addEventListener('load', function(){alert(document.getElementsByTagName('select').length)}); 
alert('stop');
```

only the first alert shows. I feel like I have made a really silly error somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply want

window.addEventListener('load', numOfSelects);

Comment: I didn't mean to copy the body and doc tags earlier.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
numOfSelects();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
window.document.body.addEventListener('load', numOfSelects);
```

By including the parentheses, you were actually calling the function and passing it's return (which was nothing) as the second argument of "addEventListener," rather than referencing the function

Comment: tried this aswell, not working either. argh! thanks though. this is irritating me, it seems so simple.

Comment: Are you still getting the same result?

Comment: Even if changing out this line of code didn't make the program function as desired, it is still a problem with the code.

Comment: when i tried what you typed, it didnt compile properly, so any code after that line did not work. What i do in those cases is wrap two alerts, i.e. alert(1); before the line of code and alert(2); after. So alert(1) only runs not the second one. However i did try this: window.document.body.addEventListener('load', alert(document.getElementsByTagName('select').length)); and that returns 0.

Comment: addEventListener takes a function handle.  By including the parenthasese, you're calling the function right then and there.  The same goes for alert.  You're not telling addeventlistener to call alert once the body is loaded, you're telling it to call whatever alert() returns, which is nothing.

Comment: Also, that code does work for me, so check and make sure it got copied correctly.


also, you could try this:

window.document.body.addEventListener('load', function(){alert(document.getElementsByTagName('select').length)});

Comment: copied that exact line, clear my js file and pasted that line. still does not work. Thought somehow maybe it was the browser. Tested out both on chrome and firefox. no success.

Comment: Can you post more code?  Because that code worked fine for me in chrome, which means that something else seems to be going on.  Do you get any console errors?

Comment: i'm going to create two new files with the most minimal code and give this another go, maybe there is something wrong with the parent file.

Comment: I didn't even see the body tags in there -that's what the other problem was.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, the answer is already given

```
window.addEventListener('load', numOfSelects);
```

Another use case may require to pass parameter in the function

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
numOfSelects(param)
});
```